# String with format returns weird output with currency as argument

Tags: swift

I have this in my playground:

```
import UIKit
let buyWithMoney = NSLocalizedString("Buy %i", comment: "")
print(String.localizedStringWithFormat(buyWithMoney, "$1"))
```

This is my output:

```
Buy 339,712
```

Why doesn't it show `Buy $1` and how can I change my code to get that output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue with format specifier which you are using for value. in your case `"$1"` is `String` not an `Integer`, so use format specifier for `String`.

```
let buyWithMoney = NSLocalizedString("Buy %@", comment: "")
print(String.localizedStringWithFormat(buyWithMoney, "$1"))
```